# Why is Tenderbake's double-baking punishment 640 tez?

Tags: baking, accuser, double-baking

I have been reading about Tenderbake and there is one detail I do not understand yet: Why is the value of `DOUBLE_BAKING_PUNISHMENT` a fixed amount of 640 tez, instead of relative to the stake or the delegated amount? And also, why is this value higher than the minimum frozen deposit of 600 tez (10% of the minimum stake of 6000 tez)?

At first I thought that the value was perhaps a typo on [the docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/consensus.html#cs-constants-lima), or an old value left there from a previous version, but I queried my own Octez node with

`$ ./octez-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants | jq`

and the JSON also showed the values `"minimal_stake": "6000000000"` and `"double_baking_punishment": "640000000"` (in micro-tez).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This amount was inherited from the value of block_security_deposit in the "Emmy era".

The more relevant and an updated value in [Tenderbake](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/tenderbake-has-been-injected.html) is that for the [punishment of double endorsements](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/consensus.html#slashing) (and double preendorsements), which is proportional to the stake.

A double bake not followed by double (pre)endorsements is of no critical consequence (one of the blocks will remain a candidate, will not be finalized) and is most probably accidental (for instance an issue with the baking setup). Therefore there is no need to punish a double bake too harshly.

Comment: I see. And I just found out that the post you linked answers my second question too: _Double baking is penalised by slashing 640 ꜩ (or the whole deposit, if less than 640 ꜩ)_. Thanks!